# Displaying image in Flutter, send through socket connection

Tags: sockets, dart, flutter, base64, ktor

I'm trying to create Server-client connection using sockets. Server is just an Echo-server. I want to send different types of data there. I've started with Images. What I want to achieve is :

1. Parse image stored in the assets folder to appropriate data type
2. Send it to Echo Server
3. Receive data back on the mobile (client) site
4. Display an image send that way (to be sure, data was send correctly)

I've implemented both Client and Server. Client is in Flutter, Server in Ktor. 
Server implementation was copied from tutorial: https://ktor.io/servers/raw-sockets.html.
What I can see, is that my server is receiving an image and sending it back correctly, but I am not able to show it.

Server code :

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val server = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp().bind(InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080))
        println("Started echo telnet server at ${server.localAddress}")

        while (true) {
            val socket = server.accept()

            launch {
                println("Socket accepted: ${socket.remoteAddress}")

                val input = socket.openReadChannel()
                val output = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

                try {
                    while (true) {
                        val line = input.readUTF8Line()

                        line?.let {
                            println("Client sent: $line")
                            output.writeStringUtf8(it)
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    println("Closing socket")
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    socket.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Client:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Socket _socket;
  List<int> _connectionTimes = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Connect to socket'),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            elevation: 4.0,
            onPressed: () {
              closeSocket();
              _connectToSocket().then((createdSocket) {
                setState(() {
                  _socket = createdSocket;
                });
              });
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Send to socket'),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            elevation: 4.0,
            onPressed: () {
              _sendMessage();
            },
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _socket,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                final bytes = base64Decode(utf8.decode(snapshot.data));
                return Image.memory(bytes);
              } else {
                return Text("no image");
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  Future<Socket> _connectToSocket() async {
    final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
    Socket sock = await Socket.connect('10.0.2.2', 8080);
    print("Connection time was ${stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds}");
    return sock;
  }

  void _sendMessage() async{
    final imageBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/dog.jpeg');
    final bytesAsString = base64Encode(imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List(imageBytes.offsetInBytes, imageBytes.lengthInBytes));
    print(bytesAsString);
    _socket.write(bytesAsString+"\n");
  }

  void closeSocket() {
    if (_socket != null) {
      _socket.close();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _socket.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The error i receive is :

```
E/flutter ( 8235): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/painting/codec.cc(97)] Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.
I/flutter ( 8235): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8235): The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 8235): Exception: operation failed
I/flutter ( 8235): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

And in addition I have some more questions:

1. Is there a better way to parse image from assets in Flutter?
2. Is there a way to send this data without adding `\n` at the end of an image data?
3. Is it possible that image would be too large, and I wouldn't be able to send it in one request? If yes, what should I change in code to make it work? Divide it to several calls and use buffer on both client and server?
4. What should I change in server code, that would allow me to run it once, and connect and disconnect with single client multiple times? (It's annoying, that with every change I make to the Flutter code, I have to rerun server so it works correctly?

I'm open for changing server implementation to another framework / language. I want to use Flutter, but it doesn't have to be Ktor on Server site. Just wanted to check it in action.

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions, but I would start by logging the data you're sending out and getting back and comparing them (after base64 encoding when sending, and before base64 decoding when receiving - probably with the smallest possible image to make the strings shorter for testing).

Comment: So I've tried really small Image (64x64 px) and my code works. I've also added check, which compares bytes (as String) which was send to server and which was received from it. For small image it is correct, Image is displayed. On larger Image (225x225) The error written above is thrown, and the string (bytes) I've received from server are completely different.

Comment: I've compared from the large image, string that is received on the Server. It is exactly the same, as it was send from Client. But sending it back to client resolves in something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use the following code to Read a jpg image from the photo gallery, send to a node.js server by socket.io, then transfer to another client(at the same time save the image in mysql, just like whatsapp send image)

```
String base64Image1 = '';

// strImage1 is the path of the photo gallery retrieved by the plugin path_provider, plus the file name of the image.
String strImage1 = gv.strHomeImageFileWithPath + '_01.jpg';

var filImage1 = new File(strImage1);

List<int> imageBytes1 = filImage1.readAsBytesSync();

// use the following line if another client wants to display this image in html
// base64Image1 = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + base64Encode(imageBytes1);

// Or, use the following line if another client wants to display this image in flutter
base64Image1 = base64Encode(imageBytes1);

// Send the b64 image string to the server
gv.socket.emit('PIBRequestPhotoClassify', [base64Image1]);
```

It seems that my codes to decode and display the b64 image string is the same as yours, but the codes to encode the image is different, pls. try.

Comment: If i placed file under `assets/images/dog.jpeg` what should i type as `filename of an image` ? I've tried doing:
`final appPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String strImage1 = appPath.path + '/assets/images/dog_small.jpeg';`

And it results in error:
`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.flutterclient/app_flutter/assets/images/dog_small.jpeg'`